# Use jQuery to remove table, cells, rows but keep contents

Tags: jquery

I have a number of tables inside an html page that I need to remove - but I'd like to keep the contents.

I have tried the below thinking it would unwrap the contents of the table, but it hasn't seemed to work

```js
$("table").contents().unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `let t = document.querySelector('table'); t.outerHTML = t.innerText;` ...?

Answer (score 0):

`.contents()` will select only the "immediate children" (https://api.jquery.com/contents/)

The browser will add an implicit `tbody` if you don't specify one, so your code unwrap()s the `tbody` only - the browser then sees a `tbody` without a `table` and so adds an implicit `table` for you.

Instead, you can `unwrap()` all the elements, including the implied tbody:

```
$("th,td,tr,tbody,table").contents().unwrap();
```

Updated snippet:

```js
$("th,td,tr,tbody,table").contents().unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```